# Issues caused by Outlook 2016 syncing with Outlook.com

Tags: windows-10, sync, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016, outlook.com

I followed this sites instructions to allow Outlook 2016 to sync the calendar and contacts with Outlook.com.

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/olc-hotmail/sync-calendar-contacts-using-outlook-com/

So basically I've done this:

I'm running Windows 10 and already had a Microsoft named after my real POP3 email account, hosted else where (let call it something@somewhere.com).

So I connected my POP3 account (something@somewhere.com) to my Microsoft account.

Setup an Exchange ActiveSync account in Outlook connecting to Outlook.com.

Moved my Calendar and Contacts out of Outlook's something@somewhere.com account, into my Microsoft account.

Ok. Everything is syncing up fine.

The problem I've got is that I don't want any email to come via my Outlook.com account. I've removed the Microsoft account from the send/receive group within Outlook 2016, which stops it pulling emails from Outlook.com.

I just can't work out how to stop email being delivered to Outlook.com. I just want to be able to sync my calendar and contacts.

Any advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disconnect your POP3 account to outlook.com. because your calendar and contact stay in outlook.com server (not in POP3, POP3 only delivery email not contact and calendar). you do not needed to connect them since beginning if you didn't want to.

Those instruction for people like to move their limit webmail server to outlook.com.

Comment: as simple as that. I thought about doing that, but for some reason I thought it would break the sync link between Outlook and Outlook.com. Nice one. Thanks for your help :)